# Transparent nav in header.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How would I use a transparent navbar with header.php properly? If the navbar is wrapped in the same div wrapper as the hero, and each page has a different hero image set by the hero div wrapper class (hero-1, hero-2, hero-3 etc), adding the navbar to header.php would mean all pages have the same hero. This is because the hero class will be hard coded in header.php where the navbar is.

How do I solve this problem? I've added some basic html to demostrate the problem

```html
<section class="hero-wrapper hero-1">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      logo here
    </div>
    <div class="nav-links">
      <ul>
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to style the navbar with position: absolute and put the hero wrapper after it (inside the template).

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp